# How to make a Matlab matrix with gradients from three corners?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I am trying to complete an assignment which is asking me to create a gradient image using a 256x256x3 matrix. The second layer of the matrix `(:,:,2)` is used for creating the green color of the gradient image. The green layer is supposed to look like this:

[image: Green matrix layer]

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
green = linspace(1,0,256);

image = zeros(256,256,3)
for column = 1:256
    image(column, :, 2) = green;
    image(:, column, 2) = green;
end
```

But this ends up making the green layer matrix look like this:
[image: Incorrect Green Layer]

So I am not really sure what to do. How can I make a matrix that would look like that?

Answer (score 0):

From OP's explanation, the problem comes down to 2D interpolation, with 255 at origin and 0 at three other vertices. Thus, we can use interpolation function to accomplish the task:

```
[X,Y] = ndgrid(0:255,0:255);    %//create a grid with coordinates
[Xi,Yi] = ndgrid([0,255],[0,255]);  %//define edge coordinates
Zi = [255,0;0,0];   %//specify green intensity at edges
Z = interpn(Xi,Yi,Zi,X,Y); %//do linear interpolation
Zim = uint8(round(Z));  %//round and convert to integers
imshow(cat(3,zeros(size(Zim)),Zim,zeros(size(Zim)))) %//show result
```

The result is this:

[image]

Or, in grayscale:

[image]